# Is it possible to enforce the same dynamic keys between interfaces in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

Given an interface `MyInterface1` with a dynamic set of keys:

Is it possible to pull the keys from `MyInterface1` to be used as keys in `MyInterface2`?

Something like:

```
export interface MyInterface1 {
    [key: string]: string
}

export interface MyInterface2 {
  [k in keyof MyInterface1]: string, // This line doesnt work :(
}
```

I saw some discussion of stuff like this here: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5683#issuecomment-376505064

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare a type alias, not an interface:

```
export type MyInterface2 = {
  [k in keyof MyInterface1]: string
};
```